# How to get static files served dynamically with Rollup (and work along with node-resolve)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rollup, rollupjs

I'm making a library based on [TSDX](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/tsdx), nice and powerful CLI for package development which is based on Rollup and allows customization of its config. I have a bunch of country flags SVGs in my project and I need to import them and show them dynamically when they are needed. It wasn't clear for me how dynamic imports are working there and is it a problem of TSDX or Rollup itself, so I opened up an [issue](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/tsdx/issues/533) in TSDX' repository about that. People helped me out so now there are two ways that I can see to achieve that:

1. Use `rollup-plugin-copy` and then require all the files statically through a switch statement.
2. Use a virtual module that exports an object containing all file names in a directory as described [here](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/2463#issuecomment-455957865) in one of the Rollup's issues (#2463).

I feel like writing a switch statement manually for all of the country flags is not the best idea in my life, so I thought that second path is better as it doesn't require me to maintain more code, because it'll just generate the code that I need. So I set up a little TSDX package for testing with a single React component that looks like this:

```js
import test from 'testmodule'

export default function () {
  return test
}
```

Now `testmodule` is what should be resolved by Rollup. I have this config now:

```js
module.exports = {
  rollup (config) {
    config.plugins.unshift({
      name: 'plugin-test-module',
      resolveId (id) {
        console.log('resolveId', id);

        if (id === 'testmodule') {
          return id;
        }

        return null;
      },
      load (id) {
        if (id === 'testmodule') {
          return 'export default "Test is successful"';
        }

        return null;
      },
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

So what should happen is I just need to see "Test is successful" in the browser. 
Unfortunately, `npm run build` fails with error `Cannot find module 'testmodule'`. I've put `console.log` into `resolveId()` to see what's happening, and looks like it never receives `testmodule` in its `id`. I replaced `unshift` with just straight assignment to `config.plugins` (so it removes other Rollup plugins) and it successfully compiled, although I understand that this is bad, so it's not a solution. I've read Rollup's docs and it seems like some other plugin added by TSDX like `node-resolve` may be trying to resolve the import instead of my plugin, but I can't find a way to stop that. So the main question is how to get my plugin to work along with others like `node-resolve`.

If you're interested about what other plugins TSDX uses, they're all can be found [here](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/tsdx/blob/master/src/createRollupConfig.ts). Seems like Rollup doesn't do tech support on their issues page so I hope somebody here is familiar enough with it to help me with this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue, with `@rollup/plugin-replace`.

```
// .. another rollup plugin
const replace = require('@rollup/plugin-replace');

rollup(config, options) {
    config.plugins.push(
      replace({
        delimiters: ['', ''],
        values: {
          '../../../assets': './assets',
          '../../../../assets': './assets',
        },
      })
    );
    // ... your other config
    return config;
  },
```

So that will replace this:

```
function Image({ name, ...props }: ImageProps) {
  const src =
    name === 'bank-indonesia'
      ? require(`../../../assets/images/${name}.jpg`).default
      : require(`../../../assets/images/${name}.svg`).default;
  return <img alt={name} src={src} {...props} />;
}
```

Into this:

```
function Image(_ref) {
  var name = _ref.name,
      props = _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose(_ref, _excluded$2);

  var src = name === 'bank-indonesia' ? require("./assets/images/" + name + ".jpg")["default"] : require("./assets/images/" + name + ".svg")["default"];
  return React.createElement("img", Object.assign({
    alt: name,
    src: src
  }, props));
}
```

I know this is really bad solution, but it works for be btw.